# SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable

Tags: react-native

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> SDK location not found. Define location with an ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at